# Detecting if value of attribute changed during last update doesnt work with Active Model Dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, attributes, activemodel

I am trying to send a notification email in my rails app only if the value of my column status was modified by the current update. I tried using Active Model Dirty as was suggested in some post and the `status_changed?` method. Unfortunately my email is never sent because @partnership.status_changed? constantly returns false even though the value of status was indeed changed during the last update. Here's my controller code :

```
  def update
    authorize @partnership
    if @partnership.update(partnership_params)
      send_notification_email
      render json: {success: "partnership successfully updated"}, status: 200
    else
      render_error(nil, @partnership)
    end
  end

  private

  def send_notification_email
    PartnershipMailer.partnership_status_change(@partnership).deliver_now if @partnership.status_changed?
  end
```

I have also included Active Model Dirty in my model :

```
class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.update` also saves the model after updating it's data, therefore resetting the dirty-values. Try using `.assign_attributes`. It will just assign the attributes, then you can check for changes, and finally remember to save the model.

Answer (score 9):

As @Thounder pointed out, the `ActiveModel::Dirty` method `<attribute>_changed?` is reset whenever you save a record. Thus, it only tracks changes between saves.

For your use case, what you want to use is the `previous_changes` method, which returns a hash with the key being the attribute changed and the value being an array of 2 values: old and new.

```
person = Person.new(name: "Bob")
person.name_changed? # => true
person.save
person.name_changed? # => false (reset when save called)
person.previous_changes # => { name: [nil, "Bob"] }
person.previous_changes[:name] # => returns a "truthy" statement if :name attribute changed
```

My pseudo-code may be wrong, but the principle works. I've been bitten by this "gotcha" before, and I wish the Rails core team would change it.

I understand their reasoning, but it makes more sense to me to track `<attribute>_changed?` after a save as well, because that seems the common use case to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method to check the changed attributes for the active record.

```
@partnership.changed.include?("status")
```

If it returns true then we have status attribute which was changed in this record.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line method you can into the model which is the best for your case :

```
after_commit :send_notification_email, if: Proc.new { |model| model.previous_changes[:status]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@partnership.saved_change_to_status?` or `@partnership.saved_change_to_attribute(:status)` as per [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_change_to_attribute).